# output string as number in velocity

Tags: velocity

I need to add 2 values together. The problem is the 2 values are passed to me as strings. They can be 2 decimal places so I can't convert to integer.

has anyone any ideas how this can be done?

Answer (score 0):

Convert them to float. float.parse(value1) + float.parse(value2)

Comment: Can you put this into a practical example, ie

Comment: I'm not sure that I understand what you are asking. It will work exactly as indicated above. You will call float.parse(value1) + float.parse(value2), where value1 and value2 is the string values you received. Are you using C#?